# 'List' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python, window

I'm trying to fill in the index location of my first_guess into my d array but im unsure what goes before the replace array function. need help lol

[CODE PIC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ktoS.png)

I created a new variable called f, and im using the d array as the list varible before  the replace function..
I have the location of the first_guess but im unsure how to input that into the replace function to replace the '_' in the d variable with the first_guess.

Answer (score 1):

replace method is for strings, not lists. If you needed replace, you could convert d to a string using `d = "".join(d)`, or use a list comprehension - `f = list((y if i == first_guess else i) for i in d)`

However you don't need replace for what you are describing. Replace finds all occurences of a string, and replaces it with a different string. You are trying to assign an element to an index, regardless of its current value.

You either need: `f = d[:first_guess] + [y] + d[first_guess + 1:]`, meaning you create a new list that takes all elements from d until index first_guess, then y, and then all elements after index first_guess

or

```
f = d.copy()
f[first_guess] = y
```

Which means "f at index first_guess gets assigned y". The reason you need to copy d in the second solution is because list assignment just creates the reference to the list, it doesn't actually a create a new one. So if you didn't copy, changing f would change d.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that replace method is for strings and not lists. Plus it replaces all instances of a character ('_' in this case) by default and you can't pinpoint the index for which the replacement has to happen.

The solution is to use list indexing to reassign values at specific list index locations that match the index of the guessed letter in the hidden_word.

Below is the code that I have come up with. I'm also a newbie to python code, so I'm pretty sure that there will be a more concise code block for this. My code takes in the possibility of repeated guesses of the same letter and improper prompts and provides appropriate "counter measures" for the same.

Cheers!

```
hidden_word =input('Enter a word')
x = len(hidden_word)
d = ['_']*x
print(".".join(d))
responses = []
while d.count('_')!=0:
    accepted_inputs=('y','n','yes','no')
    run = input("Playing? (Y = 'Yes', N = 'No')")
    if not run.lower() in accepted_inputs:
        print('Wrong input')
        continue
    if run.lower() == 'y':
        guess = input('Take a Guess')
        if guess in responses:
                print('Already guessed, try something else')
                continue
        else:
            responses.append(guess)
        for (n,m) in enumerate(hidden_word):
            if (guess == m):
                d[n]=guess
        print(".".join(d))
    else:
        break
if d.count('_')==0:
    print("Congratulations you guessed it!")
```